# ClickListener is not working in cursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, android-cursoradapter

I use ListView with CursorAdapter, every item has an edit button can edit information, It shows but when I press the edit button, it's not working.

I don't know what's wrong with it.

This is my ActivityAdapter code.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nameTV = view.findViewById(R.id.activity_name_tv);
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
    String color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("color"));

    nameTV.setText(name);
    nameTV.setTextColor(textColor);

    View row = cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_listview, null);
    Button editButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
    editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Get id
            Long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: *when I press the edit button, it's not working* does not clarify the issue, please specify what is in your logcat / what happens when button is clicked(put a break on your button click to check if the click event is responding)

Comment: Please show your `activity_item_listview`

Comment: Do not inflate a `View` in `bindView()`. The `View` parameter is already your `View`. The `row` you've inflated there is not, which is why your `OnClickListener` isn't working. Call `findViewById()` on the `View` parameter to get your `Button`, just like you did for `TextView nameTV`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks a lot. you are right.